# Drawable Full sized Image Issue

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, android-drawable, bitmapfactory

I want to need get full sized images from drawable folder but not get
I tried to last 5 days but not get
My Image resolution 1082*1673 in drawable folder. After get from drawable my image resolution 1024*1024 Please Help me..

I tried this

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.t_00);
Drawable myImage = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(res, R.mipmap.t_0001, null);
```

Comment: how do you check the resolution?

Comment: Using Debug point check resolution of drawable image